# PowerShell to pull all empty DLs with no members

Tags: powershell, csv, scripting, office365

I am hoping someone can help me here. I was able, thanks to help of Google, find a PowerShell script online that displayed all empty DLs in our environment since we are trying to do a cleanup. Here is that script:

```bsh
Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited |? {!(Get-DistributionGroupMember $_.PrimarySMTPAddress).Count} | select DisplayName,PrimarySMTPAddress | Export-Csv DLsToRemove3.csv
```

I added an `Export-Csv` to it in order to get the list into a file. I started looking through the list and noticed that some of the DLs listed actually have one member in them. At this point I tried to run another script against my CSV file to get a list of any if the DLs with one member in it and the that one member. Here is that script:

```bsh
Import-Csv "C:\Users\177626\DLsToRemove3.csv" | foreach {$Group=$_.PrimarySmtpAddress; Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $Group | select @{Name="Group";Expression={$Group}}, DisplayName | Export-Csv Members.csv -NoType}
```

When I ran that, there was no information at all populating in my CSV. I am looking for help with either being able to add the second step to the first step and combine both scripts into one or at least being able to get the second script to work to view the DLs with that one member in them.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Try this script if you need more detailed reporting on distribution group like empty distribution groups, distribution groups that has more than 'N' members, list distribution groups with their members, etc.

https://o365reports.com/2019/05/23/export-office-365-distribution-group-members-csv/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This never failed me to get the empty DL's

```
$emptyGroups = foreach ($grp in Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited) {
    if (@(Get-DistributionGroupMember –Identity $grp.DistinguishedName -ResultSize Unlimited).Count –eq 0 ) {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            DisplayName        = $grp.DisplayName
            PrimarySMTPAddress = $grp.PrimarySMTPAddress
            DistinguishedName  = $grp.DistinguishedName
        }
    }
}
$emptyGroups | Export-Csv 'C:\Users\177626\DLsToRemove4.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

The `@()` forces the `Get-DistributionGroupMember` results into an array to get an accurat `.Count` property

Comment: Hi! I marked it as the answer, thank you again. Quick question if you don't mind. Would there be a way to distinguish or mark another column as Cloud or On-Prem for the DL?

Comment: @Schmit Sure, just do `Get-DistributionGroup -Identity "somegroup" | fl *1 to see what else properties you eant and add them to the construction of the `[PsCustomObject]`.

Comment: I do not think that will work unless I create an attribute to pull by. Since all the AD groups are synced to the cloud already I cannot distinguish between what is syncing from AD and what was created in the cloud already. I looked through the whole ```| fl``` and did not see any distinguishable items in there to separate the two

Comment: @Schmit I tried googling for it, but it looks like there is no way to find ot if a group was created on premise or in the cloud. Perhaps the only useful property could be `WhenCreated` if you know the date that migration took place..

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead.

```bsh
Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited | ? { (Get-DistributionGroupMember $_.PrimarySMTPAddress | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0 } | select DisplayName,PrimarySMTPAddress | Export-Csv DLsToRemove3.csv
```

Measure-Object is more reliable when counting objects in an array.

Answer (score 1):

There's the attribute `msExchGroupMemberCount` which is maintained by Exchange, so a quicker way is to filter on that attribute using get-adgroup.

```
get-adgroup -Filter "msExchGroupMemberCount -eq 0" -Properties DisplayName,mail | select DisplayName,mail
```